# How many actions are there from $ \mathbb {Z}_n $ to $ \mathbb {Z}_2 $ with $ n \geq 2?$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, group-actions, group-homomorphism

**Exercise:** How many actions are there from $ \mathbb {Z}_n $ to $ \mathbb {Z}_2 $ with $ n \geq 2$ ?

My idea is as follows: Let $\psi:\mathbb{Z}_n \to S(\mathbb{Z}_2)\cong S_2$ be a homomorphism. Then
since $ \mathbb {Z} _n $ is abelian, it follows that  $\ker(\psi)=K/\langle n\rangle $ with $K\leq \mathbb{Z}$ such that $\langle n\rangle \; \subseteq K.$ Then $\ker(\psi)=\langle m\rangle/\langle n\rangle$ con $m \mid n.$ Note that, $$|\mathbb{Z}_n/\ker(\psi)|=|\mathbb{Z}/\langle n\rangle/\ker(\psi)|=|\mathbb{Z}/\langle m\rangle|=|\mathbb{Z}_m|=m.$$

Hence, since $\mathbb{Z}_n/\ker(\psi)\leq S_2$ then $m=1$ or $m=2.$  In this way, if $ n $ is odd there is only one action of $\mathbb{Z}_n$ in $\mathbb{Z}_2$ and if $ n $ is even there are $2$ actions.

Is this correct? Thanks so much for reading.

Comment: In general, there are $\gcd(n,m)$ group homomorphisms from $\mathbb{Z}_n$ to $\mathbb{Z}_m$.

Comment: Looks fine. Well, strictly speaking, in the case of $n$ even you have only bounded the number of actions. To show that it is actually $2$ you will need to show them. It is quite clear what they are, though.

Comment: When one says a group $G$ acts on another group $H$, it generally means that $G$ acts on $H$ via automorphisms, i.e., there exists a homomorphism $\varphi:G\rightarrow Aut(H)$. As $Aut(\mathbb{Z}_2)$ is trivial, there is only one action, that is, the trivial action.